# JS to hide menu when users click on a link or anywhere else in the page

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I'm no experienced with JS at all. I searched for a way of coding this menu and I actually managed to make it with a little CSS. However, the menu only closes when the users click on the close button. If users click on a link in the menu or anywhere else in the page, the menu stays on. The code I came up with was this one:

```js
<script>
var theMenu;
var originTop;
 
window.onload = function() {
   //Click to open the submenu
   element = document.getElementById("buttonu101541");
   element.onclick = openMenu;
 
   //Top position
   originTop = document.getElementById("buttonu100976").style.top;
   //Get the Menu element
   theMenu = document.getElementById("buttonu100976");
 
   //Close button
   closeBtn = document.getElementById("buttonu101584");
   closeBtn.onclick = closeMenu;
}
 
function openMenu(){
   theMenu.style.top = 0;
}
 
function closeMenu(){
   theMenu.style.top = originTop;
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
   #buttonu100976{
 
      transition-property: top;
      transition-duration: 1s;
      transition-timing-function: ease;
 
      -webkit-transition-property: top;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
   }

   #buttonu101541{
      cursor: pointer;
      cursor: hand;
   }

   #buttonu101584{
      cursor: pointer;
      cursor: hand;
   }
</style>
```

I honestly don't know how to get passed this point. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: can you please create a demo/ you can use jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: It would likely help others provide an answer if you said what "moving on is". i.e. what results do you expect? I'd assume you expect the menu to disappear when a link is clicked. Would that be a correct assumption?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply and I'm sorry for the delay. I'm new to this kind of forum. I didn't even know that you guys replied. Thought I'd receive a notification email. :(

user2181397 what do you mean? If you'd like to see what I'm trying to do, please check www.adielrios.com, hover over the menu icon at the upper right hand corner, hover over "saúde mental" and click on "outros transtornos". That's the JS trigger.

MikeT, your assumption is precise: that's exactly what I want! :)

Answer (score 1):

If You want to hide or show a menu with a click of a button ..You may try this..

When the "showmenu" button is clicked It show the menu;

and when the"hidemenu" button is clicked it hides the menu;

If that's what You wanted, the piece of code below may help you..

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
</ul>
</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';">hidemenu</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';">showmenu</button>
```

Comment: Hey @sangamesh. Thanks for your response. Your line of code looks so short and easy that it sounds just like what I need. It may sound dumbish, but honestly where exactly must I place it in the code I provided? :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by

1. Create a variable which will flag the state of the menu. If the menu is open set it to `true`  else `false`.Let default state be `false`
2. Add `eventListener` to `document.body` & check the flag, if it is true call `closeMenu` function(I assume it is working) & then set the flag to false;

You can look at this snippet

```
var _isMenuOpen = false; //Create a variable to point the state of the menu

function openMenu(){
   theMenu.style.top = 0;
   isMenuOpen = true; // When menu is open set it to true
}

document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){
 if(_isMenuOpen ===true){ //Check if menu is open
   closeMenu(); //call close menu function
   _isMenuOpen = false // set it ti false state
 }
})
```

Hope this will be useful

Comment: Hi @user2181397. I really appreciate your input. To be honest with you I didn't really understand what you said but if you could tell me where exactly I must place it in the code I provided it would be great. Or maybe I must place it anywhere in between <script> and </script>? :-/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".menu ul");

    if (!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});

$('a').click(function () {
    $(this).next('ul').show();
});

$('.menu ul li').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('ul').stop(true, true).hide();
});

<div class="menu">
    <a>Show Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li>link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

UPDATED:

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
    <div id="buttonu100976">
        <a>link</a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).mouseup(function (e)
        {
            var container = $("#buttonu100976");

            if (!container.is(e.target)
                && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
            {
                container.slideUp();
            }
        });

        $('#buttonu100976 a').click(function () {
            $('#buttonu100976').stop(true, true).slideUp();
        });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @wim. I appreciate your response and I'm sorry it took me so long to see it. I didn't receive a notification email so I thought no one had replied.
To be honest with you I didn't really understand what you said. Should I replace anything in the code you provided with the object reference in my project?
It would be so very kind of you if you could tell me where exactly I must place your code in the code I provided. Or maybe I must place it anywhere in between <script> and </script>? :-/
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AdrianoMarques no problem. The first bit, the javascript you place in a <script> tag in the <head> or preferably at the end of the html. Make sure you load the jquery script as well, before this script. The other bit, the html is a sample list you place in the <body>. Have a look at the fiddle I made for you. Let me know if you need more help. This is the simplest way of doing it in my opinion. With jQuery you can do stuff like fade or slide instead of just show/hide. If you can share a url of your project I can have a look for you.

Comment: Also, I used an <a> tag, instead of a <button> in your sample, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Hi @Wim. Thank you so much. I barely know what a jQuery is. And I had no idea what a fiddle was until you asked me to have a look at it. Then I realized I had to hit that little thing below your responde. :-p If you'd like to see what I'm trying to do, please check www.adielrios.com, hover over the menu icon at the upper right hand corner, hover over "saúde mental" and click on "outros transtornos".

Comment: Oh! Links only work in the home page (I'll correct that later). The slide down effect works fine, the only problem is really when users hit any link or click away of the target the menu doesn't slide back up. It only slides back up when users hit the arrow (close button). :-/

Comment: That's what the first bit is for in the script, the $(document).mouseup(function (e) means that when you click outside the container, the ul hides or sldies up. Also, when you click on any li in the list the ul (parent of li) will hide as well: $(this).parent('ul').stop(true, true).hide();

Comment: I see, in that case change this line of my script to  var container = $("#buttonu100976");

Being the id of the slide menu. If you click on any link inside the menu it will close the menu because you're linking to a new page, correct?

Comment: I pasted the <script> code in the <script> section replacing the var container = $(".menu ul") line for var container = $("#buttonu100976") but it didn't work. I didn't paste the HTML code though cuz apparently the HTML code in the fiddle says that Show Menu is the JS menu trigger and well... it isn't. Regarding the linking to a new page part, the grey links are actually anchors. So if users click on an anchor that is in the same page the page scrolls behind the JS menu. I'm so lost! :-( If you'd like to see how it is, please visit www.adielrios.com/transtornos-alimentares

Comment: Hi, I can't see the script on your site, where did you put it? Quite hard to check it out as I am not able to view the source code. This script needs jquery. I'm happy to help but I have limited access to your site. Basically you need to add jquery: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>, then add the svript using the first part (on mouse up) changing the class to your id and it should work. Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: @AdrianoMarques I have just updated sample code in my answer so it is easier to understand the above.

Comment: Hi @Wim. I really appreciate your help - and patience with me. The code is in the <head>. If you search for "<!--PHP Widget code-->" the code is right above it. I replaced my entire code with your updated one but it didn't work. I guess I understand now why is that: in my code the slide down/up effects are setup in CSS and the action/function in JS. Your code uses jQuery for the slide effects. Can't I reach the effect I want without jQuery? Or is it possible to use CSS, JS and jQuery in the same "code pack"? I wish I could just place a line of code in the <script> I made. I'm feeling dumb. :-(

Comment: No problem :) see if you can make it work with this snippet and comment out the css you got. Give it a go and let me know if you need more help.